# QWindowsContext: OleInitialize() failed: "COM error 0xffffffff80010106 RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE (Unknown error 0x080010106)"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a python script which works fine within jupyter notebook. But when I create a py file from the script and run it in command prompt there is the following error:

QWindowsContext: OleInitialize() failed:  "COM error 0xffffffff80010106 RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE (Unknown error 0x080010106)"
I couldn't find much about this error in the internet. I appreciate any help.